# Git command display inaccuracy

Tags: ios, git, git-branch

on my first computer，There is no iOSDemo.xcworkspace file in the iOSDemo directory.
run command  `cd iOSProject/`, will show git btanch is `original/feature/v1.0` which it is right.
run command  `cd iOSProject/Main`, there has iOSDemo.xcworkspace file.  will show git btanch is `original/Main`.

on my second computer, Both paths are displays `original/feature/v1.0`.

What is displayed on the second computer is correct, why is there such a difference? Request help

Comment: Thanks, I found that the difference is that the computer in question has a ‘.git’ folder in both ‘i OS Project/Main’ and ‘i OS Project’. Delete the former and it will be normal.